# Cursor unpleasantly changes during drag operation in nested elements

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

As you can see in this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/VU328/ when we are trying to drag the main draggable element (`div.outer`) every time mouse goes over `div.inner` or even when it goes outside the draggable box (i.e. goes inside `body` area) cursor quickly changes to not-allowed and immedialtely changes back to normal move.

There is the markup to show a nested situation:

```
<div class='outer' draggable='true' >
    <div class='inner' >
        abc
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the minimum Javascript code that allows default drag effect:

```
$(document.body).bind('dragover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[image: Mockup cursor movement]

It happens at least on Windows and in Chrome (36.0.1985.125 m) and in IE (11.0.9600.17207).

Is there any "standard" fix which works with html5 native drag API? (i.e. not with replacing cursor with some image or covering `div.outer` with another `div` or using jquery-ui or similar libraries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it!

You have to prevent default behaviour of `dragenter` too:

```
$(document.body).bind('dragenter', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```